# What happens with Steam trading cards from sale after the sale?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I have some cards from the current sale. They are marked as "valid until 7/4/2016, 6:00:00 PM". 
What happens after this date? Will they be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will just disappear.